# Probability drawing two cards

Tags: probability

I am trying to set up a probability table for the events of drawing two cards from a $52$ card deck. What counts is either an exact match or a match in flush with two already drawn cards from another deck. I am not sure the table is correct, so I would be grateful for a judgement.

1. Two exact matches:                        $\frac{1}{1326}$
2. One exact match + one flush match: $\frac{13 \times 2-1}{1326}$
3. One exact match only:                  $\frac{26 \times2}{1326}$
4. Two flush matches:               $\frac{13 \times13\times2-39}{1326}$
5. One flush match only:            $\frac{26 \times 26-52}{1326}$
6. No match at all:                        $\frac{325}{1326}$

Comment: oops, denominator shall be 1326

Comment: 1326 = 52 * 51 /2

Comment: Are we to assume that the two cards that were already drawn are distinct?

Comment: pt 4: 13*13-26  should be 13*13*2-39

Comment: What does it mean to have "two exact matches" if you are selecting two different cards?

Comment: Yes, the two already drawn cards are different from each other.

Comment: Exact match: the 2 cards drawn from a first and different deck macth the two drawn from the second deck in value and flush.

Comment: Let's look at your second entry, exact match and flush match. If the cards drawn from the other deck are a pair of hearts, the probability of exact match and flush match is different than if the two cards from the other deck are of different suits. Your calculation is correct for different suits. Also, probability of no match is correct if other deck cards are of different suits, but not otherwise.  Also, there are issues of definition. If the cards to be matched are Ace of spades and King of hearts, and we draw an Ace of spades and another spade, is that an exact match and a flush match?

Comment: André, thank you very much for your remarks. The answer to your question is no. Your example has only an exact match, no flush match.